# What is an overview of Jesus' ministry during Holy Week?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, judaism, easter, calendar

Starting with his arrival in Jerusalem, what is an overview of events in the final week before his resurrection as they occurred on specific days of Holy Week?

Note: I'm looking for an answer that cites sources in Catholic and Orthodox traditions and compares them if necessary, and most importantly presents the events in the context of the Jewish Passover festival calendar.

Comment: Are you looking for a particular Orthodox tradition (Greek, Russian...) to compare with the Catholic Church.. The Catholic Church already has Eastern Rite Churches. Would you accept a comparison  with either of the two Roman Rite forms in use?

Comment: @KenGraham Yes very much, I'm also very curious about how ancient or modern Jewish practices of the Passover and contemporaneous holy days influenced or informed these Christian practices.

Comment: Are you looking for a chronology / timetable?

Comment: @Geremia Yes, exactly. Sunday - Jesus is...., the Passover festival activities are.... Monday- Jesus is -...., Passover activities are...., Tuesday - etc, with learned commentary about the teaching in Tradition, from His arrival in Jerusalem until his resurrection.

Answer (score 2):

This comes from the [*Douay-Rheims Holy Bible*](https://www.baroniuspress.com/book.php?wid=56&bid=1) p. 967, "An Historical and Chronological Table of the New Testament":
<sup>(with minor updating of scriptural reference style and proper name spellings)</sup>

> A.D. 33
>
> His transfiguration, Matt. 17.

Sunday of Holy Week (Palm Sunday):
<sup>(Jesus makes the Jews' annual pilgrimage to Jerusalem.)</sup>

> The Sunday, or first day of the week, in riding upon an ass into Jerusalem, Matt. 21.
>
> In the beginning of the that week he went daily into the Temple, and in the evenings retired to Bethany, to pray in the garden of Gethsemane, Luke 21:38 etc.

Fig Monday:

"Holy Monday is also called Fig Monday because Our Lord cursed the fig tree this day (Matthew 21: 18-22). In the Extraordinary Form of the Mass, the gospel tells the story of Mary anointing Jesus' feet (John 12: 1-9), which also occurred on this day" (courtesy: [Ken Graham](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/47796/what-is-an-overview-of-jesus-ministry-during-holy-week/47877?noredirect=1#comment133378_47877))

Spy Wednesday:

> On Wednesday Judas made a bargain with the chief priests, to deliver him up to them for a sum of money, Matt. 26:15.

Maundy Thursday:
<sup>(Thursday evening was for the Jews the "First day of the Azymes," the beginning of Friday; azymes = feast of unleavened bread)</sup>

> On Thursday he sent his disciples in the afternoon to bring the paschal lamb, offered in the temple, which after sunset he ate with his twelve Apostles, Matt. 26.
>
> He washed their feet, John 13.
>
> After supper he instituted the Blessed Sacrament and Sacrifice of his Body and Blood, Matt. 26.
>
> He gave his Apostle those excellent instructions set down by St. John, 14-17.
>
> Christ's prayer in the garden three times repeated.
>
> He is there seized, being betrayed by Judas.
>
> He is led away to Annas, and then to Caiphas.
>
> He is condemned as guilty of blasphemy to death, for owning imself the Son of God. He is spit upon, buffeted, etc.

Good Friday:
<sup>(a Sabbath Day for the Jews, when they sacrificed their Pascal Lamb according to Exodus 12:1-11 and, **at the same moment**, crucified Jesus; the Jews called the evening Parasceve)</sup>

> On Friday morning they deliver him up to the Roman governor, Pontius Pilate, who sees and declares him innocent, yet fearing not to be thought a friend to Cœsar, condemns him to the death of the Cross.
>
> He dies on the Cross, and is buried. For the history of his Passion, see Matt. 26, 27, 28; Mark 14, 15, 16; Luke 22, 23, 24; John 18, 19, 20.
>
> The miracles at his death, *ibid*.

Easter Sunday:

> He riseth from the dead the third day, *ibid*.
>
> His different apparitions that very day; and others afterwards, *ibid*.

Before his Ascension forty days later:

> He gives his Apostles power to forgive sins, John 20:23.
>
> He gives to St. Peter the charge over his whole Church, John 21.
>
> He promiseth to be with his Church to the end of the world, Matt. 23.

Comment: Holy Monday is also called Fig Monday because Our Lord cursed the fig tree this day (Matthew 21: 18-22). In the Extraordinary Form of the Mass, the gospel  tells the story of Mary anointing Jesus' feet (John 12: 1-9), which also occurred on this day.

Comment: It could also be noted that Jesus was on the Cross at the very moment the people of Israel were slaughtering the Passover lamb: "The animal was slain on the eve of the Passover, on the afternoon of the 14th of Abib,[2] after the Tamid sacrifice had been killed, i.e., at three o'clock, or, in case the eve of the Passover fell on Friday, at two.[3]" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover_sacrifice

Comment: @KenGraham Yes, perhaps I could make it clearer that it was the same moment, not only the same day.